# How to add line to beginning of sed output

Tags: linux, string, bash, sed

So the problem I'm having is that I'm using sed to pull out a bunch of objects from a string in a bash script, but I need to add the same string to the beginning of the sed output. An example:

Data:

> |field1|field2|select * from object1, object2|

sed output:

```
object1|
object2|
```

What I've tried:

Sticking the whole line into a variable called `LINE`, then:

```
sed "s/^.*/$LINE&/g"
```

This resulted in an error that says:

> unknown option to s

```
echo $LINE
|field1|field2|select * from object1, object2|
```

So there's nothing wrong with the variable.

This is the desired output:

> |field1|field2|select * from object1, object2|object1|
>
> |field1|field2|select * from object1, object2|object2|

Any help is sincerely appreciated :)

-Ryan

Comment: `line='|field1|field2|select * from object1, object2|'; sed "s/^.*/$line&/g" <<< $'object1|\nobject2|'` works as expected here.

Comment: Yes it works from command line. Not from within bash script...

Comment: Then show your script!

Comment: `echo $LINE` is wrong. You need `echo "$LINE"` to show the contents of the variable `LINE`. As written, `LINE` could contain multiple newline chars and you'd never know it (except for your `sed` command failing, of course :-) ). You have several fundamental shell programming errors in your code - I recommend you get the book Shell Scripting Recipes by Chris Johnson.

Comment: Ed, while I appreciate the fact that you took the time to reply to this, I don't appreciate your reply itself. I used `echo $LINE` BECAUSE there are no newline characters. Additionally, my "code" as you so state, comprises of all of two lines in my above example, so I fail to see my "several fundamental shell programming errors" as you so state. When you're in a bad mood and feel like moaning at somebody, rather don't do it on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the characters in your string are being interpreted by sed. To avoid this problem, you should use a string-based method, rather than a regex-based one. For example, using awk:

```
awk -v line="$line" '{ print line $0 }' file
```

This adds the string in the shell variable `$line` to the start of each line in `file`.

Comment: ...actually it looks like the string is safe to use in the case you have shown but nevertheless I would recommend this approach.

Comment: I love you... Worked like a charm

Comment: This is a good advice! though, be warned that `awk` can choke on backslashes…

Comment: What @gniourf_gniourf means by `awk can choke on backslashes` is that because awk is a text-processing tool and almost always the desired behavior when looking for a regexp in text is that `\t` in the regexp be expanded to a literal tab so it finds those in the input file, that's exactly what awk does by default. In those rare occasions when that is NOT the desired behavior then you just need to double-escape (`\\t`) or use a different method of passing the value to awk (e.g. via `ENVIRON[]` or as an arg `awk '<script>' '\t' file`). The important thing is - this is DESIRABLE, not a problem!